# Has the Advection-Dominated Accretion Flows (ADAF) model been used to describe accretion flow around a rotating black hole?

Tags: black-hole, accretion-discs, accretion

I am studying Advection-Dominated Accretion Flows (ADAF) from the review paper [Advection-Dominated Accretion around
Black Holes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9803141.pdf). In section 2.1 of the paper, the authors provide the basic equations of the flow (assuming Keplerian motion) using the Newtonian gravitational potential. In section 2.4, the authors choose the [Paczynski-Wiita potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paczy%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Wiita_potential) to obtain pseudo-Newtonian global solutions around a Schwarzschild black hole.

The Paczynski-Wiita potential successfully simulates the Schwarzschild geometry quite accurately and thus the ADAF model could successfully describe the accretion flow around a non-rotating black hole. My question is follows:

Has the ADAF model been used to describe accretion flow around a rotating black hole? If yes, which gravitational potential has been used in the calculations to simulate Kerr geometry?

Comment: Section 2.5 of your review (which is from the late 1990s) mentions several papers using the Kerr geometry for ADAF calculations, and one can find more recent papers. One thing to do might be to look at papers which cite Manmoto 2000 (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000ApJ...534..734M/abstract):
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000ApJ...534..734M/citations

Comment: See this review from 2013, specifically section 7 and references therein https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5499